# Вызов функции из другого потока

Tags: python, pyqt5, многопоточность, сигналы-слоты, qthread

У меня есть окно *PyQt5*, оно существует в своем "главном" потоке. 
При нажатии на кнопку в гуи, запускается второй "бэк-енд" поток (`QThread`), там происходит открытие файлa, с последующей обработкой данных и сохранением.

**Вопрос**: как можно из "бэк-енд" потока вызвать, скажем, мэссдж-бокс в гуи с ошибкой или другой информацией?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox


class Backend(QThread):
    def __init__(self, path) -> None:
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.path = path

    def run(self):
        # file.open(self.path)
        # .......
        # file.save(other.path)
        print('Вызов фун-ии notifications(status)')
    

class MyApp(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.bc = Backend('./')

        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Начать', self)
        self.setGeometry(300,400,300,150)

        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.bc.start)

    def notifications(self, **kwargs):
        if kwargs['status'] == 'success':
            QMessageBox.information(self, 'Оповещение', 'Файл преобразован и успешно сохранен!')
        else:
            QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Ошибка', 'Что-то пошло не так')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MyApp()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Сигналы и слоты`** используются для связи между объектами. Механизм сигналов и слотов - это центральная особенность Qt и, вероятно, часть, которая больше всего отличается от функций, предоставляемых другими фреймворками.

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox


class Backend(QThread):
    mySignal = pyqtSignal(str)                       # !!!
    
    def __init__(self, path) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.path = path

    def run(self):
        try:
            # file.open(self.path)
            # .......
            # file.save(other.path)  
            
            self.msleep(2000)                       # имитируем работу 2 сек.
            #2 / 0                                  # раскомментируйте эту строку 
            self.mySignal.emit('Success')                    # !!!
        except:
            self.mySignal.emit('Error')                      # !!!               
    

class MyApp(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.bc = Backend('./')
        self.bc.mySignal.connect(self.notifications)         # !!!

        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Начать', self)
        self.setGeometry(300,400,300,150)

        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.bc.start)

    def notifications(self, text):
        if text == 'Success':
            QMessageBox.information(self, 
                'Оповещение', 'Файл преобразован и успешно сохранен!')
        else:
            QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Ошибка', 'Что-то пошло не так')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MyApp()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Это решило мою проблему, буду изучать матчасть!

Comment: @AlexPetrov пожалуйста. Удачи вам.